# Why Does "setval()" Fail With "relation ... does not exist"?

Tags: postgresql

If you attempt to set a sequence number like this:

```
SELECT setval('table_ID_seq', (SELECT max("ID") + 1 FROM table));
```

You might encounter the following error:

```
ERROR:  relation "table_ID_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT setval('table_ID_seq', (SELECT max("ID") + 1 FROM t...
                      ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "table_id_seq" does not exist
SQL Status:42P01
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that PostgreSQL will normalize identifier names unless they are put in double quotes.

However, this will not work:

```
SELECT setval("table_ID_seq", (SELECT max("ID") + 1 FROM table));
```

Instead, you will have to put single-quotes around the double-quoted text:

```
SELECT setval('"table_ID_seq"', (SELECT max("ID") + 1 FROM table));
```

Comment: Though this is definitely in the docs, that probably can't be more unobvious. Thanks!

Comment: Go home, Postgres, you're drunk :)

Comment: 3 hours spent to figure wtf is going on... you saved my day.

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: You made my day! I'm lucky for having found your solution after only one day. Thank you so much.

Comment: Wow! Postgres has got to be kidding me. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

With all the previous tips the error still persists. I identified the need to perform a conversion from numeric value to integer.

It's necessary to force an integer return.

```sql
select setval ('YOUR_ID_SEQ', (select cast (max (YOUR_COLUMN) as integer) from YOUR_TABLE));
```

Comment: Is this because you don't use `+ 1` here? The plus 1 is necessary to not reuse the same number and avoid 0 as the very first ID (1-based IDs).