# Sequelize node js create record with autoincrement field validation error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have sequelize model:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Image = sequelize.define('Image', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
            autoIncrement: true,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        url: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    });

    Image.associate = (models) => {
        //some association here
    };

    return Image;
};
```

I am trying to create a new record like that:

```
const img = await Images.create({
    url: '/newUrl'
}).catch(error => {
    throw errors.initError(error);
});
```

it executes a query

> Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Images" ("id","url") VALUES
>   (DEFAULT,'/newUrl') RETURNING *;

and I receive an error

```
{
  "message": "id must be unique",
  "type": "unique violation",
  "path": "id",
  "value": "18",
  "origin": "DB",
  "instance": {
    "id": null,
    "url": "/newUrl"
  },
  "validatorKey": "not_unique",
  "validatorName": null,
  "validatorArgs": []
}
```

Should not sequelize handle autoincrement field by itself?

Comment: Perhaps changing it to `SERIAL` instead would do? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: BigInt id works okay for other models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you have manually created entries into the database providing the `id`.

To demonstrate this, you can try these into postgres

```
create table users (id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(40));
insert into users (name) values ('abhinavd');
select * from users;
insert into users (id, name) values (2, 'abhinavd');
insert into users (name) values ('abhinavd');
```

The last insert will fail complaining that `id` must be unique

[image: Duplicate key]

Comment: So how do we get it to start auto incrementing again?

Comment: It would be great to provide a solution for the issue

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have inserted a record and have provided the id manually. next_val('test_id_seq') is only called when the system needs a value for this column and you have not provided one. What you need to do is to update this next_val value.

To fix this you can execute the following in your table

```
   SELECT setval('YourTable_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) from "YourTable"));
```

The name of the sequence is always autogenerated and it follows the following format tablename_columnname_seq.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works very fine and fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Rodolofo's answer, Postgres users should replace `'YourTable_id_seq'` with `'"YourTable_id_seq"'`. Table name is case-sensitive.

[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484061/14817088)